# pandas, row wise dot product

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame here

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':[1,2,3,4,5,9],
                'COL2':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   COL1  COL2
0     1     5
1     2     3
2     3     6
3     4     9
4     5     2
5     9     4
```

How can I multiply a vector `[2, 1]` row-wisely so that `df` is

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   COL1  COL2
0     2     5
1     4     3
2     6     6
3     8     9
4    10     2
5    18     4
```

Comment: It's worth nothing this isn't a true dot product.  This is row-wise multiplication for each index in each vector.  The dot product of the vector [2, 1] for each row would result in a scalar, so the end result would be a Series of scalar values, the length of the original dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiple by `numpy array`:

```
print (df * np.array([2,1]))
   COL1  COL2
0     2     5
1     4     3
2     6     6
3     8     9
4    10     2
5    18     4
```

Or by `Series` with same index as columns of df with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (df.mul(pd.Series([2,1], index=df.columns), axis=1))
   COL1  COL2
0     2     5
1     4     3
2     6     6
3     8     9
4    10     2
5    18     4
```